# Converting a HashMap using moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I'm trying to convert a `HashMap` of elements into a JSON string. I'm using the method used in this [link](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/173).

```
 val elementsNew: HashMap<String, Element> = HashMap(elements)
 val type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map::class.java, String::class.java, Element::class.java)
 var json: String = builder.adapter(type).toJson(elementsNew)
```

But this gives the following error

> Error:(236, 40) Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer
>   parameter T in fun  adapter(p0: Type!): JsonAdapter!
>   Please specify it explicitly.

Can any one tell me where's the fault? Is it because of Kotlin?

Comment: worth noting that it's not exactly because of Kotlin. In Java, you'd end up with `JsonAdapter<Object>` (wouldn't be able to use that for your `Map<String, Element>` type). Kotlin forces you to provide the parameterizing arguments, so you can see the mistake sooner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the signature of the `adapter()` method, it can't infer its type parameter from the argument:

```
public <T> JsonAdapter<T> adapter(Type type)
```

Hence you have to provide the type explicitly:

```
var json = builder.adapter<Map<String, Element>>(type).toJson(elementsNew)
```

or alternatively:

```
val adapter: JsonAdapter<Map<String, Element>> = builder.adapter(type)
var json = adapter.toJson(elementsNew)
```

Comment: This did work. I thought since the link didn't have templates, it won't need them.

Comment: I like the first one, declaring the type parameters explicitly and keeping the implicit declaration type. also, less code.